# How do I receive an intent in an Android service?

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-service, android-notifications

My problem goes something like this: I have a service that creates notifications; if one of the actions in the notification is selected, I would like a particular function in the service to run.

So far I have the following code to add the "stop" action to my notification:

```
// Stop action intent.
Intent stopIntent = new  Intent(this, LockService.class);
stopIntent.setAction(STOP_ACTION);  // Stop action
PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this, 0, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation,
        "Stop", stopPendingIntent);
```

I also have a Broadcast Receiver all ready to go! It's stored locally, however...

```
BroadcastReceiver stopReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received an intent!!! " + intent.getAction());
    }
};
```

My logs tell me that this is run when my service is created, so the receiver should be active in the service...

```
IntentFilter stopFilter = new IntentFilter();
stopFilter.addAction(STOP_ACTION);

this.registerReceiver(stopReceiver, stopFilter);
Log.i(TAG, "Receiver stopReceiver registered.");
serviceRegistered = true;
```

Unfortunately, stopReceiver's onReceive is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intent was too specific -- I changed it from this over-specific request...

```
Intent stopIntent = new  Intent(this, LockService.class);
```

to this code instead.

```
Intent stopIntent = new Intent();
```

Specifying a class and a context is NOT the way to go for a broadcast intent, apparently!